# Database access in PHP Silex does not work?

Tags: php, database

i have an problem to get a database access with Silex. (micro Framework for PHP). I tried it really often.

```
      $app->register(new Silex\Provider\DoctrineServiceProvider(), array(
      'db.options' => array(
      'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
      'host'     => 'mysql_read.someplace.tld',
      'dbname'   => 'userdatas',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => 'sqlroot',
    ),

    $app->get('/blog/{id}', function ($id) use($app){
    echo "Zweites Hey";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM logins WHERE ID = ?";
    echo "Drittes Hey";
    $post = $app['db']->fetchAssoc($sql,array((int) $id));
    echo "Lool";

    return "Die Zahl ist:" . $post['ID'];
```

Comment: Whats the error you get with this?

Comment: There wasn't a error. There were only nothing.

Comment: Check your logs to get the fatal error message.

Comment: Where can i find the logs?